# Custom Installer to install, execute db script and for coniguration settings in .net

Tags: .net, installation

I like to create a custom installer to install web application, windows application by let the user to use check box, execute db script and let the user do coniguration settings, in .net.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://wix.sourceforge.net/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when this sort of functionallity is required, one of two things is done.

Either a developer will create the required functionallity as custom script or an extension within an installation building package (such as InstallShield, WISE etc).

Alternatively the functionallity will be created as a stand-alone executable that is run by the installer at the appropriate time.

Depending on what installer you are using one my be easier than the other.

If you are looking for a free install builder, [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is used fairly extensively.